# zsh - where to set the path to .zshrc config file

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I changed my MacBook user name, so the path to my .zshrc file needs also to be updated to Users/new-user-name/.zshrc since zsh is still looking at the old path Users/old-user-name/.zshrc and of course cannot find anything anymore there.

Where does zsh get the path to the file or rather where can I set it?

I hope my question is clear. I am not looking for the .zshrc file itself and I don't want to add a path inside this file. I want to tell zsh that the file has another location.

I would be happy to get help with this :)

Comment: Have you tried: 'source ~/.zshrc'. If you don't have a .zshrc file in your new $HOME, you can move the file from the old $HOME to your new user's $HOME path and the "source".

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about. Thank you very much! Worked!